# Http post requests in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

I'm sending two HTTP requests. The first one is the Login request for authorizing and a second request for creating some user data. The Login call works fine but on the second call I'm getting the error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},
"lazyUpdate":null},
"status":404,
"statusText":"Not Found",
"url":"localhost:4200/… failure response for localhost:4200/api 404 Not Found"
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798) 
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:sourcemap:412)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:sourcemap:64550)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:sourcemap:411)
    at Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:sourcemap:180)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:sourcemap:582)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:sourcemap:497)
    at invokeTask (polyfills.js:sourcemap:1634)
```

How do I find out what or where the problem is?
I assumed the error was because the second API did not have auth info from the first to work properly but passing the response of api1 to api2 does not do anything either.

The code for sending the requests where I tried passing there response. (Although I still think this isn't correct but I'm not sure and nothing else is working): 
service.ts

```
Login() {
    let promiseResult : any;
    this.http.post<any>('/Login', this.auth_payload).toPromise().then(data => {
      promiseResult = data;
      console.log("Login call" ,promiseResult)
      return promiseResult

    });
  }

    data = this.Login()
    Create(data) {
      let promiseResult : any;
      this.http.post<any>('/Create', this.create_payload).toPromise().then(data => {
        promiseResult = data;
        console.log("set Information call" ,promiseResult)
        return promiseResult

      });
    }
```

component.ts

```
  onSubmit(){
    this.authService.Login()
    let call = this.Service.Login()
    return call 

  }
  data = this.onSubmit

  SetVital(){
    let data = this.onSubmit
    this.authService.Create(data)
```

Comment: what is schedule_payload?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's the data that the API needs too set/create the info.

Comment: data required by api should be second parameter, third parameter will be headers and all.

Comment: Okay. And should I send the authorization response in this data? (I see now that my use of variables was a bit misleading)

Comment: request json in second parameter, headers and all in third parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just add `'/Login'` to your api path it will requst to `localhost:4200/Login` for resources, thats what happening here, please try to add your correct path in requsts
correct api path
assume that your api is running on `localhost:3000/api` then change your requst like this

```
 Create(data) {
     const baseurl = 'localhost:3000/api/Create'
     return this.http.post(baseurl, this.create_payload);
     }
```